# How to fetch a field from the response which we are getting from the API in Angular 6

Tags: angular

My problem is that I do not have any `getAll()` method over web API. The only thing I could see when I hit my Angular app is at the network, the entire JSON is available over the network `http:localhost:8080/api`. Now I just want one field i.e. `contractId` from the obtained json.

```
{
  "contractId": 44,
  "contractName": "BOND",
  "contractServiceList": [
    {
      "id": 44,
      "serviceId": 1,
      "providerTier": null,
      "coinsurance": 35,
      "copay": 547,
      "penaltyApplies": "Y",
      "penaltyRule": "Non Emergency ER Use",
      "penaltyType": "Coinsurance",
      "penaltyValue": 890,
      "deductibleApplies": "Y"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can someone help me how to achieve this?

All the other fields are going as Form Submit from UI but Id is auto-generated at backend whose value at the time of form submit I want.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to get `contractId`

I assumed your request method as **GET** and  **response json** as:

```
{
  "contractId": 44,
  "contractName": "BOND",
  "contractServiceList": [
    {
      "id": 44,
      "serviceId": 1,
      "providerTier": null,
      "coinsurance": 35,
      "copay": 547,
      "penaltyApplies": "Y",
      "penaltyRule": "Non Emergency ER Use",
      "penaltyType": "Coinsurance",
      "penaltyValue": 890,
      "deductibleApplies": "Y"
    }
  ]
}
```

Get Data :

In Service :

```
import {
    HttpClient,
} from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

this.http.get('http:localhost:8080/api').subscribe((resp: any) => {
    console.log(resp.contractId)
});
```

Reference ===> https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: I guess u did not get my question. I mentioned I do not have have any direct GET method from Web API but in Inspect Element, it's showing as this url consists of the response then how I would be able to get it. http.get would not help I guess.

Comment: So  as i understood u dont know whats the request method is? right?

Comment: No...I just have one question when I am doing form submit Iam passing contractName and the list, not the contractID but when I do Inspect Element, I would be able to see it in Network tab the entire json framed. How is that coming? Bcoz I want the fetch the value from that response. I do not have http.get there.

Comment: If you prefer, we can join chat for this clarification.

Comment: Ok I need more details.

Comment: I did some research and I found it's possible through HttpInterceptor and Caching. Could you please help me how to do that, I will again give u a brief of my question. I want to fetch HTTP Response from Angular but I only have POST method to Web API.